# DataContract to be used in a dedicated Data Access Layer class?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontract, circular-reference

I am playing around with WCF 4.0. I have a simple service with the following as DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class WeeklySchedule
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateMon;
    [DataMember]
    public string DishMon;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTue;
    [DataMember]
    public string DishTue;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateWed;
    [DataMember]
    public string DishWed;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateThu;
    [DataMember]
    public string DishThu;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateFri;
    [DataMember]
    public string DishFri;
}
```

I want to build a separate class library to hold the database access methods. I want these methods to return the WeeklySchedule objects.

How can i do this avoiding circular reference?

If i reference the DAL class to the WCF service i can use the db methodss, but the DAL class cannot "see" the DataContract class.

Comment: you could treat WeeklySchedule as a DTO and populate it from yourDB entity. either in a manager class or some adapter style thing.

Comment: i am sorry if i made you think that i have enough experience on OOP...:) can you please write a thing or two about your proposal?

Comment: you mean not to use the WeeklySchedule class at all in my DAL class and return a plain list for example?

Comment: This should make it make a bit more sense http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object

Comment: Thanks, i am reading about, but is there a way to have a common definition of my structure and share it in these 2 classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added a third 'layer' which we call application.  It has access to the DTO (your class defined in your question) and the data layer.  The application layer then acts as the one that has a view of everything.  It gets the data from the data layer and has the job of populating the data contract prior to returning it to the caller.  So it will do a bulk of your service work.

This avoids your circular reference.  :)

Comment: But the WCF needs the datacontract declaration in it , no? I mean if i take pout the datacontract in a separate class above both the DAL annd WCF how the WCF must operate?

Comment: The data returns from the DAL and it is (as an example) an Entity Object.  In the app layer you then move the data from the Entity object to the Data contract object.  That is what is returned which is also what WCF needs.

Comment: How to return the ready datacontract to the wcf. In wcf code will i have the declaration of the datacontract class or not? or i will have something else?

Comment: Your DTO objects are your data contracts.  Defined in your interface, created in your Application Module, consumed by your WCF application.  So you have this:  Service is Called.  Service Creates List of Entity Objects.  Application Layer Creates a List of DTO objects from the list of Entity Objects.  WCF Layer Consumes the DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my lack of knowledge , i thought that if i separated the DataContract and ServiceContract classes from the WCF service class i would have problem.

The solution to my question was to create a common class library for contracts and have them accessed by either the WCF class or the Data Access Layer class.